# Contour plot with 90 degree angles

Tags: r, plot, contour

I have a matrix, say `cmat <- matrix(c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1),3,3)` and I would like to plot the **exact** contours of the "region" with containing ones.

When using a `contourplot(cmat)` what I get is lines that define a sort of "smoothed" contour rather than following exactly the tiles. What I would like is a graph made only out of vertical and horizontal lines.

Does anyone know a function performing that?

Thanks in advance,
Renzu

Comment: Use ggplot2 and its `geom_tile`. You can easily find tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found my tutorials for filled surfaces, none however that show how to draw just a line. Could you kindly point me to one?